# Storage::download working wrong in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-storage

I have a file in path:

> app/public/template/templateeSkillsMatrix_Config.docx

and when i use:

```
return response()->download(storage_path('app/public/template/eSkillsMatrix_Config.docx'));
```

It is working, but when i use :

```
return Storage::download(storage_path('app/public/template/eSkillsMatrix_Config.docx'));
```

It show an error:

> File not found at path: E:/project/agl/nav/New folder/DKMH/storage/app/public/template/eSkillsMatrix_Config.docx

I dont know why.
I read [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#downloading-files) , but i dont understand what is parameter of it.

Please help!

Comment: `Storage::download(..)` will automatically use the base storage path so you can just say `Storage::download('app/public/template/eSkillsMatrix_Config.docx')` assuming the storage root is the same `storage_path`

Comment: if i do like yoy, it will show error "File not found at path: app/public/template/eSkillsMatrix_Config.docx"

Comment: Have you created symbolic link of that folder in public directory as mentioned in the laravel docs.

Comment: Yep, i create it with artisan command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @apokryfos's comment ,Storage::download(..) will automatically use the base storage path so i dont need call storage_path method. I need to call it the following:

```
return Storage::download('public\template\eSkillsMatrix_Config.docx');
```

in this line, i removed storage_path method and delete app/ in path.

and it is working for me!